# How Can I Remove mdf and ldf File In SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this code:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.sysdatabases WHERE name='MyDatabase')
begin
   DROP database MyDatabase
end
Go

CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase
```

But I see this error after executing this query:

> *Cannot create file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.FARASQL\MSSQL\DATA\MyDatabase.mdf'*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely your database was offline when you tried to `DROP` it. In such case SQL Server leaves db files on filesystem. It's intentional behavior.

According to [DROP DATABASE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178613.aspx)

> Dropping a database deletes the database from an instance of SQL
>   Server and deletes the physical disk files used by the database. **If
>   the database or any one of its files is offline when it is dropped,
>   the disk files are not deleted.** These files can be deleted manually by
>   using Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 3):

Drop the database is just to bring it offline. You need to manually delete the mdf and ldf file ([see here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49811/location-of-the-mdf-file-of-the-database) on how to locate them); then refer to this image:

[image]

After that, you can recreate the database.